# How to render partial inside template

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am using angular 2 for a project and i want to render a partial inside a template without creating a component. Is that possible?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-showroom-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/ng2-showroom-template.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  pipes: []
})
@RouteConfig([

])
export class Ng2Showroom {

}
```

ng2-showroom-template

```
<!-- import navigation.html here -->

<p>
  Hello World
</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Oops! I don't understand your question.

Comment: In other words, how to render a template inside another template.

Comment: do not know, just run a command inside ng2-showroom-template.html to import another template.html file

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirement. But I don't know if is possible.

Comment: I don't think that's supported.

Comment: ng-include is not an option?

Comment: There is no `ng-include` but as the answer below mentions, you can just add another component. But you can't bind from the template of this component to the current components field, at least not directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your template is part of another component, call it, NavigationComponent which has a selector of 'navigation-component', then you can add that tag to your ng2-showroom-app template and add the navigation component as a directive...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {NavigationComponent} from 'src/navigationComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-showroom-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/ng2-showroom-template.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavigationComponent],
  pipes: []
})
@RouteConfig([

])
export class Ng2Showroom {

}
```

```
<navigation-component></navigation-component>

<p>
  Hello World
</p>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But I'm guessing what you are really going for is the more common scenario of a master page that has HTML that is always there, and then a template that gets swapped out, based on navigation...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Page1Component} from 'src/page1component';
import {Page2Component} from 'src/page2component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-showroom-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/ng2-showroom-template.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  pipes: []
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/page1', as: 'Page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: '/page2', as: 'Page2', component: Page2Component }])
export class Ng2Showroom {

}
```

```
<p>HTML always shown above content, regardless of navigation.</p>

<a [routerLink]="['Page1']">Link to Page 1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['Page2']">Link to Page 2</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<p>HTML always shown below content.</p>
```

Now when they click on 'Link to Page 1', whatever you've defined in Page1Component will display within the `<router-outlet>` placeholder.

Comment: hmm i go the gesture and its kind of the second approach what i was looking for thank you!